# Is it possible to save the latest backup from a Time Machine backup drive?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have an old Time Machine backup drive containing backups of my old laptop. I would like to format and repurpose the drive, but at the same time want to archive the latest backup in case I ever need to revisit it in the future. Is it possible to save my latest Time Machine backup on the drive, to another drive?

Being able to save it as a sparse bundle or other container file to reduce the number of individual files being saved would be an added bonus, as there would probably be millions of tiny files, considering all the applications and system files being backed up.

Comment: Time Machine backup are directory trees. All files inside are not copies but just physical links. If you delete one tree you just loose one backup. One backup tree is independent of the others. You can see this by comparing the size of each backup. I saw this at the beginning of Time Machine, I don’t know if there have been changes since.

Comment: For what externals cost, label drive, put drive on shelf, buy new external.